# `token` does not live long enough when pass into the HeaderValue in rust

Tags: rust

I am learning using rust to write a http client, before send the http request, I want to read the token and put it into header. now I am facing a issue that:

```
`token` does not live long enough
```

this is a minimal example to reproduce this issue:

```
use rust_wheel::config::app::app_conf_reader::get_app_config;
use reqwest::{
    header::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue},
};

fn main() {
    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    let token = get_app_config("cv.x_access_token").to_owned();
    headers.insert("x-access-token", HeaderValue::from_static(&token));
}
```

and this is the `Cargo.toml` configuration:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"]}
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0" }
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["json"] }
```

I think the `HeaderMap` has a long lifetime than `token`, so I tried to clone the token like this:

```
headers.insert("x-access-token", HeaderValue::from_static(&token.clone()));
```

seems did not work. what should I do to fixed this lifetime issue? I also tried `as_ref()`, but I think clone is the proper way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HeaderValue::from_static` requires a string slice with static lifetime.  Instead, use [`HeaderValue::from_str(&token)`](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/header/struct.HeaderValue.html#method.from_str).