# Rust error: does not live long enough. borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I have the following rust code.

```
async fn propagate_header<B>(state : State<MyGlobalVariables>, req: Request<B>, next: Next<B>) -> Response {
    let valid_algorithm_string = state.valid_algorithm.join(",");
    let mut res = next.run(req).await;
    res.headers_mut().insert("valid_algorithm", HeaderValue::from_static(&valid_algorithm_string));
    res
}
```

This gives error:

```
error[E0597]: `valid_algorithm_string` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:55:74
   |
53 |     let valid_algorithm_string = state.valid_algorithm.join(",");
   |         ---------------------- binding `valid_algorithm_string` declared here
54 |     let mut res = next.run(req).await;
55 |     res.headers_mut().insert("valid_algorithm", HeaderValue::from_static(&valid_algorithm_string));
   |                                                 -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                                                 |                        |
   |                                                 |                        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                 argument requires that `valid_algorithm_string` is borrowed for `'static`
56 |     res
57 | }
   | - `valid_algorithm_string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I have tried adding `.clone()` at the end of the `valid_algorithm_string` statement but that continues to fail too with same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [`token` does not live long enough when pass into the HeaderValue in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76347724/token-does-not-live-long-enough-when-pass-into-the-headervalue-in-rust)